# Django form has defualt HTML required

Tags: python, html, django

My sign up page has the HTML required attribute for the form fields, 'instrument1, 'instrument2, 'level1' and 'level2'. I never used required in the form or html so I'm wondering why it's popping up and how to disable it. Thanks.

forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(RegisterForm):
    instrument1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    instrument2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    level1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    level2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(TeacherSignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.instrument1 = self.cleaned_data['instrument1']
        user.instrument2 = self.cleaned_data['instrument2']
        user.level1 = self.cleaned_data['level1']
        user.level2 = self.cleaned_data['level2']

        user.teacher = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

By default each form fied defined explicitly is [`required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.required). You can change it by adding `required=False` argument:

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(RegisterForm):
    instrument1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
```

**UPD**

Alternatively you can use [`use_required_attribute`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.use_required_attribute) form's attribute but this only remove `required` HTML attribute for required fileds. Fields still be required during form validation process:

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(RegisterForm):
    use_required_attribute = False
```